# How can I give a struct a pointer to the first element of a matrix in C, and then print different elements of the same matrix using that pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct

I wanted to have a struct in C with the dimensions and a pointer to the first element of a matrix, and then use that pointer to print out different elements of the same matrix.
Instead it doesn't print out anything and gives a warning when I try to compile my code.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Matrix
{
    int height; // matrix height, first dim
    int width; // matrix width, second dim
    int** firstE; // first matrix elem
} matrix;


int main()
{
    int m1[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; //example of two-dimensional array
    matrix matrix_1 = {3,3,m1};
    
    printf("%d\n",**(matrix_1.firste));     //should output 1
    printf("%d\n",**(matrix_1.firste + 1)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n",*(*(matrix_1.firste)+1)); //should output 2
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The warning itself:

```
.\example.c:14:32: warning: initialization of 'int **' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   14 |         matrix matrix_1 = {3,3,m1};
```

I figured the code I made would work, because the code below does what I intend to do.
What I expected was that I could give "m1" to the struct above as "int**".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m1[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; //example of two-dimensional array
    
    printf("%d\n",**(m1)); //should output 1
    printf("%d\n",**(m1 + 1)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n",*(*(m1)+1)); //should output 2
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common misunderstanding in C. Array of pointers in not a 2D array.

In your case you need to assign pointers to int arrays to an array of pointers to int:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *m1[3] = {(int[]){1,2,3},(int[]){4,5,6},(int[]){7,8,9}}; //example of two-dimensional array
    matrix matrix_1 = {3,3,m1};
    
    printf("%d\n",**(matrix_1.firstE));     //should output 1
    printf("%d\n",**(matrix_1.firstE + 1)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n",*(*(matrix_1.firstE)+1)); //should output 2
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vMM5aaqc9

As a side note: use `size_t` not `int` for sizes

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and arrays have a close relationship, but they are completely different things.  Therefore, although you can form an array of pointers or an array of arrays, these, too, are different things.  C 2D arrays are of the latter variety -- arrays of arrays.  The corresponding pointer type is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer, which is exactly what your error message is telling you.

It would be possible to write your `struct Matrix` so that the initialization you present would work, but if the accesses in the `printf` statements are also to work as expected then that would require a fixed width for the matrix to be defined in `struct Matrix`.  Example:

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    int height;       // matrix height, first dim
    int width;        // mostly irrelevant
    int (*firstE)[3]; // first matrix row
} matrix;

// ...

    int m1[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; //example of two-dimensional array
    matrix matrix_1 = {3,3,m1};
```

However, for what you seem to have in mind, you probably want a *single* pointer to the first element of the first row.  This will require you to perform indexing calculations manually:

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    int height; // matrix height, first dim
    int width; // matrix width, second dim
    int *firstE; // first element
} matrix;


int main()
{
    int m1[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                     { 4, 5, 6 },
                     { 7, 8, 9 } }; //example of two-dimensional array
    matrix matrix_1 = { 3, 3, m1[0] };
    
    printf("%d\n",*(matrix_1.firstE + matrix_1.width * 0 + 0)); //should output 1
    printf("%d\n",*(matrix_1.firstE + matrix_1.width * 1 + 0)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n",*(matrix_1.firstE + matrix_1.width * 0 + 1)); //should output 2
    
    return 0;
}
```

That shows the full index calculation in each case, but of course you could simplify each one.  In practice, however, I expect that you would write a macro or maybe a function to obtain elements, for clarity and to reduce the risk of mistakes:

```
#define MATRIX_ELEMENT(m, r, c) ((m).firstE[(m).width * (r) + (c)])

// ...

    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 0, 0)); //should output 1
    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 1, 0)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 0, 1)); //should output 2
```

You can assign to that, too:

```
    MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 1, 1) = 42;
```

Do note, however, that that macro evaluates the expression designating the matrix twice, which is an issue if that expression has any side effects.  I don't see a way to avoid that in a function-like macro -- you would need to go with an actual function, which would inherently resolve that issue:

```
int matrix_element(matrix *m, size_t r, size_t c) {
    return m->firstE[m->width * r + c];
}

// ...

    printf("%d\n", matrix_element(matrix_1, 0, 0)); //should output 1
    printf("%d\n", matrix_element(matrix_1, 1, 0)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n", matrix_element(matrix_1, 0, 1)); //should output 2
```

In that case, you would need a separate function for storing elements.

On the third hand, you could conceivably combine a (single) function and a macro to avoid the problem with side effects and also avoid the need for multiple functions:

```
int *matrix_element_p(matrix *m, size_t r, size_t c) {
    return m->firstE + m->width * r + c;
}

#define MATRIX_ELEMENT(m, r, c) (*matrix_element_p(m, r, c))

// ...
    MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 1, 1) = 42;

    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 0, 0)); //should output 1
    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 1, 0)); //should output 4
    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 0, 1)); //should output 2
    printf("%d\n", MATRIX_ELEMENT(matrix_1, 1, 1)); //should output 42
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element of `int[3][3]` matrix is an `int[3]` array. So the type of the member must be a pointer to this array. The meber type must be `int(*)[3]`. Unfortunately, the size of inner array is going fixed. A workaround is using a pointer to incomplete array type `int(*)[]`. The disadvantage of incomplete types is that they cannot be dereferenced. Therefore, the original type has to be reconstructed, preferably by using a pointer to VLA.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Matrix
{
    int height; // matrix height, first dim
    int width; // matrix width, second dim
    int (*arr)[]; // first matrix row
} matrix;

void print_matrix(matrix m) {
  int (*mat)[m.width] = m.arr;
  for (int y = 0; y < m.height; ++y) {
   for (int x = 0; x < m.width; ++x)
    printf("%d ", mat[y][x]);
   puts("");
  }
}

int main() {
  int m1[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; //example of two-dimensional 
  matrix m = { 3, 3, m1 };
  print_matrix(m);
}
```

It compile without a warning and works perfectly. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cYWxM7z3E).